# Firestore emulator - connecting on a custom port

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

As described in [the firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator#tests_only_pass_the_first_time_you_load_the_emulator) I can set the port for the firestore emulator in firestore.json by adding the section:

```
  "emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "port": 1234
    }
  }
```

But how do I connect to it then? Do the initializeTestApp and initializeAdminApp take the port as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find this in the documentation anywhere, but was able to figure it out by looking in the source of the [`@firebase/rules-unit-testing` npm package](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/541944bf236017e353c5b1ac38c5956cfc8606dd/packages/rules-unit-testing/src/api/index.ts#L35).

All you need to do is set the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable:

```
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8181
```

Then just use `initializeTestApp()`/`initializeAdminApp()` as described in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests).

(It looks like you can also use the `DATABASE_ADDRESS_ENV` environment variable if you're using the RealtimeDatabase instead.)

Answer (score 0):

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype#instrument_your_app_to_talk_to_the_emulators

> ```
> // Initialize your Web app as described in the Get started for Web
> // firebaseApp previously initialized using firebase.initializeApp().
> var db = firebaseApp.firestore();
> if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
>   // Note that the Firebase Web SDK must connect to the WebChannel port
>   db.settings({
>     host: "localhost:8081",
>     ssl: false
>   });
> }
> ```

Could you try the following samples?

- https://google.dev/pathways/firebase-emulators
- https://google.dev/codelabs/firebase-emulator-get-started#0

Comment: My test cases fails to connect to the emulator using this. I get an error message when loading the rules "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses"

Comment: Not sure what you added or removed... But no it is still not working

Comment: At first, you should try any samples. If it is not working then the problem may be your PC settings.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the [firebase emulators documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure) and set a different port (5010 versus 5000) for hosting in the `firebase.json` file within my Flutter app.  Instant success.